# vision navigation in indigo

Tags: slam, imu, navigation, kinect, freenect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm searching a package which could be used for `real-time vision navigation` in indigo.
Some people advice me to use [rgbdslam](http://wiki.ros.org/rgbdslam) , but it can't work in indigo.

Anyone else could tell me if there is package that could solve my problem?

I only have a `kinect x360` and a `IMU`, and I use `ubuntu 14.04` and `indigo` , I want to let my robot avoid obstacles in my workspace.

Thanks first.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211219/vision-navigation-in-indigo/) by [wsAndy](https://answers.ros.org/users/21662/wsandy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 224 on 2015-06-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to the wiki, rgbdslam is made for fuerte, not indigo, that is probably why rgbdslam isn't working. You can try looking into OpenCV and applying it for your setup. My advice would be to write a vision node dealing with information from your kinect, then have that vision node publish data to your navigation node, but keep researching, maybe somebody will have a better idea.

---

Originally posted by [jbrown](https://answers.ros.org/users/21640/jbrown/) with karma: 101 on 2015-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1